# Fade on hover using toggle system

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-animate

When I hover an item, something else should be visible. This works, but how can I animate it? I want it to fade in instead of becoming plain visible.

```
function toggle(){
    var workshopscontainer = document.getElementById("workshops-container");
    workshopscontainer.classList.toggle("toggle");
}

$(".clip").hover(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    toggle();
});
```

This is the javascript code I'm using to toggle a class which makes the item visible.

I've been trying to put a transition on the opacity, but it doesn't seem to work

```
.toggle {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;

}
```

EDIT html included

```
<div class="clip-wrapper">
        <div class="clip">
            <p>Workshops</p>
            <img name="workshops" alt="workshops" src="_img/wpic.png" width="422" height="750" />
        </div>
        <div id="workshops-container" class="toggle">
            <div class="workshop">
                <img name="workshop1" alt="workshop1" src="_img/ws1.png" width="placeholder" height="placeholder" />
                <header>
                    <h1>Workshop 1</h1>
                </header>
                <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="workshop">
            <img name="workshop2" alt="workshop2" src="_img/ws2.png" width="placeholder" height="placeholder" />
                <header>
                    <h1>Workshop 2</h1>
                </header>
                <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ? , describe _"doesn't seem to work"_ ? `transition` not appear at `css` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Well, it just appears, without any transitions. I've included the html btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilizing `handlerIn` , `handlerOut` of [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) , `.fadeToggle()`

```js
$(".clip").hover(function() {
  $("#workshops-container").fadeToggle()
}, function() {
  $("#workshops-container").fadeToggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clip-wrapper">
        <div class="clip">
            <p>Workshops</p>
            <img name="workshops" alt="workshops" src="_img/wpic.png" width="0" height="0" />
        </div>
        <div id="workshops-container" class="toggle">
            <div class="workshop">
                <img name="workshop1" alt="workshop1" src="_img/ws1.png" width="placeholder" height="placeholder" />
                <header>
                    <h1>Workshop 1</h1>
                </header>
                <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="workshop">
            <img name="workshop2" alt="workshop2" src="_img/ws2.png" width="placeholder" height="placeholder" />
                <header>
                    <h1>Workshop 2</h1>
                </header>
                <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you put `jQuery` tag, then you could use [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/).. More or less, something like this:

```
$(".clip").hover(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#workshops-container").fadeIn();
});
```